# NSTimer var BAD ACCESS in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, nstimer, swift-playground

Just declaring a variable like this:

```
var timer = Timer()
```

gives me this error:

error: Playground execution aborted: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

Then I need to initialize it from a button action using scheduledTimer

Comment: Call `scheduledTimer`? https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer

Comment: The behaviour of the initializer taking `()` is _undefined_ for `Timer`. Use any of the defined initializers or the factory methods.

Comment: You may also need `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true`